# rails has many relation through other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 4 tables, All of them are connected to each other.

```
restaurant -> has_many -> menus
menu -> has_many -> categories
category -> has_many -> menu items
```

I tried to access categories from restaurant through menu table and it is not working

I want to access categories and menu items from restaurant table, is it possible

for example

```
Restaurant.find(1).categories
Restaurant.find(1).menu_items
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `has_many :through` association. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Add in `Menu` model

```
has_many :categories
has_many :menu_items, through: :categories
```

Add in `Restaurant` model

```
has_many :menus
has_many :categories, through: :menus 
has_many :menu_items, through: :categories
```

If you look at generated a sql code it'll show you using 'INNER JOIN` operations.